# Do recent episodes of the Welcome to Night Vale podcast contain spoilers for the novel?

Tags: suggested-order, welcome-to-night-vale

The popular podcast *Welcome to Night Vale* recently had a novel released (October). Being a fan of the series, I purchased the book with every intention of reading it.

Unfortunately, I have had less time to read than I would like, and now there have been two or three episodes of the podcast released since the novel was published. So I wonder...

Do the episodes since the publication of the novel include spoilers (in either the main content of the episode or the behind-the-scenes introduction)?

Comment: Please add the name of the work to the title, or add a tag

Answer (score 2):

Bonus Episode #5 is an excerpt from the novel
In episode 76 Cecil starts off the broadcast with:

> The last couple weeks, as we all know, have been eventful ones. I’m not going to go over everything again – we all know what happened. We are well read, well informed people who have paid attention to the whole recent “KING CITY” affair. We know about the terrible ordeals that Diane Crayton and Jackie Fierro endured. We know how their troubles all ended up. And we know the truth about The Man in the Tan Jacket. We know all about him now, because of what Diane and Jackie found out. So I won’t go over all of that.

But that's it.